# Which file is used to retrieve data from a web server into android device

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am in a running application where i need to retrieve some dynamically generated files into my android device. Currently i am using general file system which contain string.

In that string i have some images links also, so when i start AsyncTask for those images into android device.

I want to know some suggestion about other best file system that use in android programming. For my technique i got some unfortunately stopped error. SO i need some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, mostly `JSON` is used due to its super simplicity!

See a sample:

```
{"nodes":[{"title":"The War","hlsVideo":"http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/war_0.jpg?itok=r73ka-ev","alt":""}},{"title":"Disney Nature","hlsVideo":"http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/disneynature-oceans-trailer.jpg?itok=H9WzMjMh","alt":""}},{"title":"Big Buck Bunny","hlsVideo":"http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/Big%20Buck%20Bunny.jpg?itok=OYj4s_Et","alt":""}},{"title":"Adventure","hlsVideo":"http://sample.vodobox.net/skate_phantom_flex_4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/adventure.jpg?itok=IDS3aMpN","alt":""}},{"title":"Baby Fun","hlsVideo":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws-autoscale/upload/Babies+Scared+of+Farts+Compilation+2014+%5BNEW+HD%5D/Babies+Scared+of+Farts+Compilation+2014+%5BNEW+HD%5D_master.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/baby_0.jpg?itok=GEnXunhX","alt":""}},{"title":"Apple Talk","hlsVideo":"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/steve-jobs-talk.jpg?itok=UiFsfZlX","alt":""}},{"title":"Animals in Wild","hlsVideo":"http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/wowzaid3/playlist.m3u8 ","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/o-BEAVER-facebook.jpg?itok=WP_DOXhC","alt":""}},{"title":"Kitten","hlsVideo":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws-autoscale/upload/CatCats.m3u8","videoTumbnail":{"src":"http://aws-autoscale.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/styles/large/s3/kitten.jpg?itok=E2SjBjFr","alt":""}}]}
```

In this case I have a Video Thumbnail , description and the URL, I can either use a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` to populate the items in Android.  Again it depends upon your specific requirements, using `JSON` you can dynamically change the items. Hope it helps!